# How to execute custom task when agent type differs from previous agent type in the resource in anylogic?

Tags: java, triggers, installation, task, anylogic

I'm building a multi product manufacturing system with AnyLogic 7.

There are multiple resource pools, each with a different number of resources.
There are multiple types of products - agent with various parameters, one of them being ProductType (String).

I'm trying to execute a setup task (consisting on a delay) whenever a specific resource changes the type of agent it is operating.

If a given resource just finished operating a product of type A and receives a product of type B to operate, it should execute a setup task (toolkit changeover).

I've tried using Custom tasks but the trigger is only time or schedule based.

Any idea on how to execute such function?

Thank you in advance,

Luís

Answer (score 0):

have you played around with preparation and wrap-up branches? Sounds like a wrap-up task your resource should do:
[image]

Hope this puts you in the right direction...

Comment: Unfortunatelly wrap up wasn't enough as I couldn't relate its action with the the agent entering the service/seize block parameter.
I managed to solve this using the "on seize" action and updating the processing time to include an extra setup time if the agent type changed.

Thank you anyway!